# Making http calls from swing application to a servlet, session not saved

Tags: java, swing, session, servlets

I'm creating a Swing application that connects to a web server, running some servlets (created by myself). On the 1st time a user connects, he get a "playerID" that is saved on his session on the servlets. When I try to make another call from the Swing application to the servlet, the "PlyaerID" seems not to be recognized. I'm making a simple call to get the PlayerID. The servlets recognize this type of request and send a JSON with the "playerID" and if it is not set (null) than it sends -1. The swing application always getting the "-1" reply from the servlet. I tried running it from a browser and everything was just fine.

Is it possible that my Swing client can not make a request and a session will not be saved on the servlet?

I can tell you for sure that the swing method that communicate with the servlet works well.

Comment: Cookies are probably not persisted across requests in your client. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455856/cookies-turned-off-with-java-urlconnection on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servlet session is backed by a cookie. You basically need to grab all `Set-Cookie` headers from the response of the first request and then pass the `name=value` pairs back as `Cookie` header of the subsequent requests.

It's unclear what HTTP client you're using, but if it's [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), then you could use the [`java.net.CookieHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html) for this.

```
// First set the default cookie manager.
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

// All the following subsequent URLConnections will use the same cookie manager.
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
// ...

connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
// ...

connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) - Maintaining the session
- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)