# how to add session id using URLConnection

Tags: java, httpsession

I am trying to upload an image to a server using server url. For this i am using `java.net` api.
After sending request , it is returning a response that shows session invalid. 
I am getting the session id from that server but unable to add it.
How can i add session id using `HttpURLConnection` while sending request to server.
Is their any way to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455856/cookies-turned-off-with-java-urlconnection this might help

Comment: I am getting session invalid from the server as a response

Comment: @mtk because cookie holds session ID

Answer (score 7):

Session ID is stored in a cookie, in JavaEE its name is `jsessionid`, and you add it like that:

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(
    "Cookie","JSESSIONID=" + your_session_id);
```