# HTTP Post request in Java for facebook is not working properly?

Tags: java, web, http-post

String httpsURL = "https://m.facebook.com/login/identify/?ctx=recover&c=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin%2F&lwv=100&_rdr";

```
    String query = "email="+URLEncoder.encode("myemailaddress@gmail.com","UTF-8"); 

    URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length())); 
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)"); 
    con.setDoOutput(true); 
    con.setDoInput(true); 

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());  


    output.writeBytes(query);

    output.close();

    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() ); 



    for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() ) 
        System.out.print( (char)c ); 
    input.close(); 

    System.out.println("Resp Code:"+con .getResponseCode()); 
    System.out.println("Resp Message:"+ con .getResponseMessage());
    ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVUc3.png)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RihL.png)
```

Comment: What problem do you have with this code?

Comment: Please provide more detail. What is not working properly, i.e. what do you expect this code to do and what does it actually do? Read [help] for more info on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Output  should show the html code for the result of search email address(e.g- myemailaddress@gmail.com) but It showing the code of default url which used to search accounts

Comment: Maybe It's not taking email as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the below 2 changes to your code to make it work:

1) Removed the _rdr parameter from the end of the URL. Looks like when you add that, it always redirects you to the initial page. So:

`String httpsURL = "https://m.facebook.com/login/identify/?ctx=recover&c=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin%2F&lwv=100";`

2) When following redirects, HttpsURLConnection doesn't set cookies it got from the original response, unless you do this ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455856/cookies-turned-off-with-java-urlconnection)):

`CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());`

Putting these two together, we have the final working code below. Here is a [working demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWHlzRlpVZmhpaEE). I added BufferedReader to read the response for slightly better looking console output, this is not necessary for it to work.

```
  String httpsURL = "https://m.facebook.com/login/identify/?ctx=recover&c=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin%2F&lwv=100";

  String query = "email=" + URLEncoder.encode("myemailaddress@gmail.com", "UTF-8");
  CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

  URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
  HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
  con.setRequestMethod("POST");
  con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
  con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)");
  con.setDoOutput(true);
  con.setDoInput(true);

  DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());


  output.writeBytes(query);

  output.close();

  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));



  for (int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read())
     System.out.print((char) c);
  input.close();

  System.out.println("Resp Code:" + con.getResponseCode());
  System.out.println("Resp Message:" + con.getResponseMessage());
```

Comment: I used Apache HttpClient And it worked, may be it includes cookie manager